# How to show variable names when stepping through compiled C code disassembly with Eclipse debugger?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt, disassembly

I have the following C program.

```c
// main.c

int main(void) {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    return 0;
}
```

When I step through the disassembly with Visual Studio 2019's debugger on Windows, I see the following output, which shows C code followed by the corresponding instructions.

```
     7:     int x = 10;
 mov         dword ptr [rbp+4],0Ah  
     8:     int y = 20;
 mov         dword ptr [rbp+24h],14h  
     9:     int z = x + y;
```

When I select `Show Symbol Names` from the right-click context menu, the addresses on the stack are displayed as their corresponding variable names (e.g., `[rbp+4]` is shown as `[x]`).

```
     7:     int x = 10;
 mov         dword ptr [x],0Ah  
     8:     int y = 20;
 mov         dword ptr [y],14h
```

I'd like to enable similar functionality when debugging in Eclipse 2020-09 with CDT 10.0.0.202009071455 on Linux. I'm compiling with `gcc -g main.c`.

The following is shown when stepping through the disassembly, regardless of whether `Show Symbols` is selected from the right-click context menu.

```
  int x = 20;
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0xa
  int y = 30;
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x14
```

Is there some way to have e.g., `[rbp-0xc]` be shown as `[y]`, as it would be in Visual Studio? I've tried stepping through disassembly using `gdb` directly and I encounter the same issue, where addresses are shown instead of labels. Is there some option in addition to `-g` that I need to use when compiling? I've tried both `gcc` and `clang`.